# How can update and save column in ruby activerecord in one command?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

i'm doing this:

```
work_status.progress = 90
work_status.save!
```

and i'd like to do this:

```
work_status.progress.set! 90
```

Do you know of a way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do as

```
work_status.update_attribute(progress: 90)
```

[`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute)

> Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure.

If you want to perform validations when updating, use [`#update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) instead.

You can also do :-

```
 work_status.update(progress: 90)
```

[`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update)

> Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record, all wrapped in a transaction. *If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned.*

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods to do this `update_attribute` and `update_column`. They both have the same signature:

```
work_status.update_attribute(:progress, 90)
work_status.update_column(:progress, 90)
```

There is however one important difference between those methods. **`update_attribute` is evil** - it is saving the whole model, not only given attribute and it skips all the validations. Imagine following snippet of code:

```
user.email = 'invalid email'
user.update_attribute(:points, 90)
```

This will save an email attribute as well, even though it is invalid (since update_attribute do not validate model)

Instead, you should use `update_column` which only saves a single attribute to a database leaving the rest as they are:

```
user.email = 'invalid email'
user.update_column(:points, 90)     # this updates points column in database
user.email                          # => 'invalid email'
user.reload.email                   # 'invalid email' has not been saved in database
```

Comment: Humm But has [*three limitations*](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns) too, *Validations are skipped*, *Callbacks are skipped* and *updated_at/updated_on are not updated.*.. Just for future readers.. That's why it is *fastest* LOlzz :-)